# Problem due to double quote while parsing csv.

Tags: python, csv

I have csv file in the follwing format,

```
"1";"A";"A:"61 B &amp; BA";"C"
```

Following is my code to read csv file,

```
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ';', quotechar = '"')
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

The problem is, it breaks row in 5 fields,

```
['1', 'A', 'A:61 B &amp', ' BA', 'C']
```

Whereas I was expecting my output to be,

```
['1', 'A', 'A:61 B &amp; BA', 'C']
```

When I remove double quote before 61 B in the csv file, I get output as,

`['1', 'A', 'A:61 B &amp; BA', 'C']` which is perfectly fine, but why is double quote in the middle of the field is causing problem even though delimiter and quotechar has been defined?

Comment: What happens if you don't specify a quotechar?

Comment: If if don't specify a quotechar,I result I get is , ['1', 'A', 'A:61 B &amp', 'BA"', 'C'], so it still breaks the field.

Answer (score 8):

Your csv file is invalid. If a quote occurs inside a (quoted) string, it must be escaped by doubling it.

```
"1";"A";"A:""61 B &amp; BA";"C"
```

would result in

```
['1', 'A', 'A:"61 B &amp; BA', 'C']
```

How should the CSV module guess the difference between quotes that delimit an item and quotes within the item?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the double-quote should be replaced by &quot;.

Answer (score 1):

you defined a delimiter that is in use in your text: the ampersand entity has a semicolon.  I'd recommend changing your delimiter to something that will not show up in the text.  (like a pipe character or something.)